# why references not working when using dbschema tool?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, create-table

I use DBSCHEMA tool and want to execute a query but I got this error:

```
syntax error at or near "id"
position 209
```

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE user_info (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  full_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  birthday VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  sex VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  profile_image VARCHAR,
  verified SMALLINT DEFAULT 0,
  legend VARCHAR NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY id REFERENCES user(id)
)
```

Comment: what database platform? Tag appropriately.  Where is the USER table definition

Comment: postgresql, https://dbschema.com/download.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

First, this is not valid SQL:

```
FOREIGN KEY id REFERENCES user(id)
```

The column(s) needs to be surrounded with parenthesis (keep in mind that a foreign key could involve more than one column):

```
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES user(id)
```

Then: `user` is a reserved word in Postgres, so it needs be quoted when used as an identifier - which has the side effect of making the identifier case-sensitive. Assuming that you created this table as all lower-case, you would do:

```
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES "user"(id)
```

But it would *really* be a better idea not to use a reserved word as table name: I would recommend renaming the table to something else if you have a chance to.

**[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jGqRAhel)**

Comment: thank you! The problem was what you describe, I have used a reserved word user.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-foreign-key/) the column(s) defined for the constraint should be in parenthesis; in addition, `user` should be delimited.

```
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES "user"(id)
```

[fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ywEKo5M7)